# web2py: How to update form field value onvalidation

Tags: python, web2py

I have a sample which looks quite like the one in the web2py-docs:

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#onvalidation

*models/db.py:*

```
db.define_table('numbers',
    # Field('user_id', 'reference auth_user'),
    Field('user_id', 'integer'),
    Field('b', 'boolean'),
    Field('c', 'integer')

# db.numbers.user_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db.auth_user.id)
db.numbers.user_id.writable = db.numbers.user_id.readable = False
db.numbers.id.writable = db.numbers.id.readable = False
```

*controllers/default.py:*

```
def my_form_processing(form):
    if not form.vars.b:
       form.vars.c = None

# @auth.requires_login()   
def insert_numbers():
   # record = db(db.numbers.user_id==auth.user_id).select().first()
   record = db(db.numbers.user_id=1).select().first()
   db.numbers.c.show_if = (db.numbers.b == True)
   form = SQLFORM(db.numbers, record)
   if form.process(onvalidation=my_form_processing).accepted:
       session.flash = 'record inserted'
       redirect(URL())
   return dict(form=form)
```

but added some "magic":

- In my original code the form requires you to be logged in and always loads the record with the *user_id == auth_id*. To simplify things the record for *user_id==1* is always loaded.
- If checkbox 'b' is not checked, hide field 'c' (see: [Conditional fields](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators?search=show_if#Conditional-fields))
- If checkbox 'b' is not checked and the form is submitted, clear value 'c' (see: [onvalidation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#onvalidation))
- FTR: if the record does not exist it will be INSERTed, if it already exists it will be UPDATEd. (web2py-magic).

This works quite well (the database-value of c is set to NULL if the 'b' is false) but here is the catch:

- Check 'b' (field 'c' is shown) and enter a value in 'c' and submit the form. (b = True and c = $value in database) -> Fine.
- The form is shown again with a checked 'b' and $value in 'c' -> Fine again.
- Uncheck 'b' (field 'c' will get hidden) and submit the form. (b = False and c = Null in database (because of *onvalidation=my_form_processing*)) -> Fine too!
- The form is shown again with an unchecked 'b' only but if you check 'b' again field 'c' has still $value in it (instead of an empty field).

How can I clear the form-value of field 'c'? (If I just reload the page while 'b' is False, 'c' will be an empty field. This problem only occurs on submit).

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: After checking my sample code with my real code I just figured out that the _redirect(URL())_ line was missing all the time. Now it works. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simply conditionally delete that variable, one way to do it would be the following:

```
def insert_numbers():
   record = db(db.numbers.user_id=1).select().first()
   db.numbers.c.show_if = (db.numbers.b == True)
   form = SQLFORM(db.numbers, record)

   if form.validate(message_onsuccess = 'record inserted'):
       if not form.vars.b:
          del form.vars.c
       db['numbers'].insert(**form.vars)
       db.commit()   # just to be safe
       redirect( URL(...) )
   return dict(form=form)
```

Comment: Hmm... After the change from _form.process()_ to _form.validate()_ (with _db[].insert_) the database is not getting updated. Did I miss something?

Comment: @dpat - Made some edits that should fix it. I'm guessing it was the 'next' param within 'validate()' that was screwing things up.